# Fedora 15 doesn't find wireless connection

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager

I have Fedora 15 installed on a partition in a Dell laptop.  The laptop reports wireless capability in a certain Intel Centrino family, and the drivers for all of these should be in the kernel, according to Intel.  The wireless is available to other systems (including the same laptop while booted in Windows 7), but I'm getting nothing showing up.

I specified the access in Network Manager, with the "connect automatically" box checked, and nothing.  I have one of those little function key traps that turns wireless on and off; neither making sure it's on in Windows 7 and rebooting into Fedora, nor pressing the key while in Fedora, works.

Any ideas on how I can get the wireless working?  (I'm open to trying another distro if necessary.)

**Additional information**

Computer is a Dell Inspiron N7110, Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030.

The network controller info on `lspci -v` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 008a (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5325
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at f1a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iwlagn
```

When I try to turn the wireless on and off, I get this in /var/log/messages:

```
Oct 30 14:03:50 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  791.627815] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
Oct 30 14:03:50 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  791.627847] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
Oct 30 14:03:50 Yog-Sothoth NetworkManager[797]:  WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
Oct 30 14:03:51 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  791.856562] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, address 4
Oct 30 14:03:51 Yog-Sothoth systemd[1]: Service bluetooth.target is not needed anymore. Stopping.
Oct 30 14:03:52 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  793.517232] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
Oct 30 14:03:52 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  793.517260] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
Oct 30 14:03:52 Yog-Sothoth NetworkManager[797]:  WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
Oct 30 14:03:53 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  793.822596] usb 2-1.5: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
Oct 30 14:03:53 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  793.943924] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=0189
Oct 30 14:03:53 Yog-Sothoth kernel: [  793.943935] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci`, which should have an entry for the wireless adapter (only when the adapter is on per the function key). When you press the function key, does any message get added to a file in `/var/log`? If so post these messages. Also tell us what your exact laptop model is, in case someone has experience with this particular model.

Comment: Your issue is the `Capabilities: <access denied>`. Can you check that you have the relevant modules and firmware loaded? `lsmod | grep iwl*`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [NetworkManager debugging hints](http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging) for general details on how to debug failing wireless connections in a GNOME environment.  If the problem is not obvious to you from looking at the logs (e.g. `/var/log/messages`), please include the relevant part of them in your question. (It's hard to answer your question in this general way.)